# How do redirect to a subdirectory of a website

Tags: php, redirect, apache

I have a FAQ database/web app that I would like to setup as a subdirectory to another website. So for example my main website is:

Www.domain.com

I would like people to type in:

www.domain.com/FAQs

And the files for the FAQ database are served from:

/var/www/FAQs

Do I edit httpd.conf or do I create some type of .htaccess file to create this type of behavior?

Comment: configure your web root to be /var/www/ should do it

Answer (score 1):

If your server root folder for the domain is already /var/www/ then you don't need to do anything. Just create the FAQs directory and stick an index file in it.

Do note however that for most platforms URLs are case sensitive.